# Node.js Authenticate with Token ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create a login request for my server. What am I trying to learn is 
How to create a token when the user logged in. After I created a token, I want to control user's requests with that token. Here are my code's examples. Please tell me where am I going wrong. If the all way is true, can you explain to me how to create it?

```
    var port = 8080;
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var session = require('express-session');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "123456789",
    database: "circles",
    debug: false
});

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log('UNCAUGHT', err.stack);
});

var app = express();
app.use(express.static("localhost" + "/public")); //use static files in ROOT/public folder
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({secret: 'letsputasmile',
                proxy: true,
                resave: true,
                cookie: { maxAge : 2628000000 },
                saveUninitialized: true
                }));

app.get("/", function(request, response){ //root dir
    response.send("Hello!!");
    console.log(response);
});



app.post("/register", function (request, response) {
    var name = request.body.name;
    var username = request.body.username;
    var pass = request.body.pass;
    var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(pass,salt);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(username);
    console.log(pass);
    con.query("Insert Into user(name,username,password) Values(\"" + name + "\"," + "\"" + username + "\"," + "\"" + hash + "\")",
        function (err,result) {
        if(err) response.send("nop");
        else response.send("success");
        });
});

app.post("/login", function(request, response) {
    var username = request.body.username;
    var pass = request.body.pass;
    var passer;

    con.query("select password from user where username = " + "\"" + username + "\"",function (err, result) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(result.length === 1) {
            passer = result[0].password;
        }
        bcrypt.compare(pass, passer, function (err, res) {
            if(res) response.send("success");
            else response.send("nop");
        });
    });
});

app.listen(port);
```

Comment: What is `session` in this case? Please update your code.

Comment: @ralphtheninja I uploaded everything. I think I couldn't understand the session part

Comment: but what are you trying to accomplish? you need a token to use it on another app?, or a token to use it inside the same webapp?

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa I'm gonna use it on another app(an android app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to create a `jwt` (json webtoken). You basically sign some payload (whatever meta data you want to give to the client) and the client can then pass the token back when requesting something and the server can verify the token (symmetric key) if it's correct and also parse out data the server needs, e.g. `user_id` or similar.

Check https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken for more information